# Show modified lines in the left side of the file in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

Webstorm shows which lines have been edited in a file with colours on the right. Blue means modified, green means a new line.

[image]

Is it possible to have this colour coding on the right instead of the left? It would be easier for me to see exactly what's been edited that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-changes-information.html#local_changes) are normally shown in the left gutter if **Highlight modified lines in gutter** is enabled in **Settings | Editor | General**:

[image]